# InDesign PNG Not Exporting Text Smoothly

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, export, png

Whenever I export a design as a PNG, the text on it looks all funny:

[image]

It reminds me of when, in Photoshop, you mess around with the 'font smoothing' bit of the character panel.

Except in InDesign, there appears to be no settings like this... nor when I export.

The only thing I can think of would be the anti-aliasing option, but that is checked anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to export png in higher resolution and later resize images in Acdsee (using batching) or Photoshop (using actions). I use this method constantly because many fonts has bad hinting instruction, which are causing x-height jumping (like in your sample).

Another solution is to convert all text into outlines before exporting.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think I ended up exporting a PDF at 300dpi in the end and resizing in Photoshop... it fixed the text issue but had some subtle outlines around type for some reason, not too noticeable though. I'll try a high-res PNG next time though... also good shout about converting to outlines, hadn't even thought of that! Thanks for the tips